# What's the best way of clearing a list so I can re-add the elements for ColdFusion 9 ORM?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, many-to-many, coldfusion-9

Let's say I have a `Store` and a `Product` entity, with a many-to-many relationship between them, and both are persistent CFC's.

I want to update an existing `Store`'s products using a list of product IDs from a form POST, which means that I have to first remove all the products. What's the best way of doing this? So far I've tried using `ArrayNew(1)`:

```
<cfscript>
    store = entityLoadByPK("Store", FORM.id);

    // clear the products by assigning it to a new array
    store.setProducts(ArrayNew(1));

    // re-add the products
    for (id in productid)
    {
        product = entityLoad("Product", id);
        store.addProduct(product);
    }

    entitySave(store);
</cfscript>
```

And I've tried to remove the products using a loop:

```
<cfscript>
    store = entityLoadByPK("Store", FORM.id);

    // clear the products by removing them with a loop
    for (product in store.getProducts())
    {
        store.removeProduct(product);
    }

    // re-add the products
    for (id in productid)
    {
        product = entityLoad("Product", id);
        store.addProduct(product);
    }

    entitySave(store);
</cfscript>
```

Both work fine, but is there a better way of handling this? Or does it not matter and both will do the same thing behind the scenes (namely in the SQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these functions in `store.cfc`.  Optionally, check if `variables.products` exists first.

```
void function clearProducts()
{
    arrayClear(variables.products);
}

void function addProducts(required Array ps)
{
    for (var p in ps)
        ArrayAppend(variables.products, p);
}
```

Then in Controller layer

```
var hql = "from Product where id in (:productIDs)";
var products = ormExecuteQuery(hql, {productIDs=Form.productID});

if (!store.hasProduct())
    store.setProducts(products);
else
{
    store.clearProducts();
    store.addProducts(products);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty nice solution!

Comment: :) Glad you like it.  Vote it up!